# Не получается обновить запись в бд

Tags: php, sql

```
$result=$db->mquery("UPDATE `goods` 
                     SET `name`=".$_POST['name'].",`price`=".$_POST['price'].",`description`=".$_POST['description'].",`create`=".date('Y-m-d H:i:s').",`pic`=".$uploadfile."                          
                     WHERE `goods_id`=?", 
                     array($_POST['goods_id'])
                    );

function mquery($query, $value=array()){
        $pieces = explode('?', $query);//разделим пришедший запрос на части, приняв за разделитель знак вопроса
  $entry = sizeof($pieces);//рассчитаем количество частей

        if ($entry > 0){//если количество частей больше нуля
            $query = '';//инициализируем переменную для конечного запроса
            $value = array_map(array("db_", "envelope"), $value);
            $i=0;

            foreach ($pieces as $piece){//перебираем все части запроса для того, чтобы между ними расставить переменные из массива
                $value_current = $value[$i];//получаем очередную переменную из массива
                $query .= $piece.$value_current;//объединяем ее с текущим куском запроса и добавляем к переменной конечного запроса
                $i++;
            }
        }

        if ($result = $this->link_db->query($query)){
            if (!is_object($result)){
                return $this->link_db->insert_id;
            }

            $data = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: кто такой `mquery` ? и где хоть какое-то описание ошибок, которые получаются?

Comment: выкиньте весь код что тут написан и начните использовать [PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)

Comment: Насколько вы уверены, что никто не пришлёт вам данные, которых вы не ожидаете?

Comment: Почему для where у вас используется placeholder, а для вставляемых данных нет?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже отметили выше, весь этот самопал надо выкинуть, и использовать ПДО

```
$sql = "UPDATE goods SET name=?,price=?,description=?,create=NOW(),pic=? WHERE goods_id=?";
$data = array($_POST['name'], $_POST['price'],$_POST['description'],$uploadfile,$_POST['goods_id'])
$result=$db->mquery($sql, $data);
$id = $result->insertId();

function mquery($query, $value=array()){
    $stmt = $this->link_db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($value);
    return $stmt;
}
```